# Heap/memory corruption when returning rvalue reference from factory function

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I have a class like so:

```
class CObj
{
public:
   CObj(std::string const& str) : m_str(str) {}

   static CObj&& Current()
   {
      CObj uxid{"test"};
      return std::move(uxid);
   }

private:
   std::string m_str;
};
```

I use it like so:

```
CObj obj{CObj::Current()};
```

The `std::string` inside of `obj` is corrupted/invalid. I expected to move the temporary from the factory and move-initialize `obj`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Returning a reference to a local is just as bad with an rvalue reference as an lvalue reference. Simply return by value `static CObj Current() { return {"test"}; }` and let the compiler handle the moving for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of `Current` is a reference type. You are returning a reference to a local object which will be destroyed before the callee tries to access it to construct `obj` resulting in undefined behavior. The fact that the return type is an rvalue reference has no bearing on this fact, the problem would be the same with an lvalue reference return type.

If you want to return a freshly created object from a function, you should return it by value:

```
static CObj Current() {
  return {"test"};
}
```

or:

```
static CObj Current() {
  CObj uxid{"test"};
  // do stuff with uxid here.
  return uxid;
}
```

A local returned by value will be moved automatically, although it's more likely the compiler will apply Return Value Optimization and construct the object directly in the return value without any moves or copies.